# Reading and writing an array in a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array inside a .txt file. What I want to do is

1. Reading the length of this array
2. Appending this array

```
a=[('a'),('b'),('c')]
f=open("file.txt","w+")
f.append(a[0])
```

I could not find a way to use my txt file as if an array. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] including the expected result?

Comment: You could use json instead of a regular text file.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are trying to append to a file object? And yes, I would recommend json if you don't mind losing your tuples.

Comment: You do realize, don't you, that those parentheses in your value for `a` are doing nothing--they are *not* creating any tuples. Also, please be much more specific what you mean by "use my txt file as if an array."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write things onto the end of the file, you need the following code:

```
with open("file.txt","a") as f:
    f.write("insert text here")
```

In general, the `with open("file.txt","a") as f:` syntax is preferable as one needn't manually close `f`.

You could then write each item appended on a new line thus:

```
def fileappend(filename,string):
    with open(filename,"a") as f:
        f.write(string)
```

This would allow you to extract the strings thus:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    l=[x[:-1] for x in f.readlines()]
```

`l` would then contain a list of the items appended to the file, which admittedly would not be able to contain newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as a string

```
myString = f.read()
```

Split the string on a given character and store it as an array (technically a list). You have not provided details on the format of your file so I will assume that it is comma delineated.

```
a = myString.split(',')
```

A faster way to do this is

```
a = f.read().split(',')
```

To get the length

```
len(a)
```

To append

```
a.append("thing")
```

To append to the file you have to open it in append mode. This is denoted by the second argument in the `open` method

```
f = open(filename, 'a')
f.write(",thing")
```

Comment: But that method doesn't actually append the thing to the file, which is what the OP was after...

Comment: The OP's directions were unclear to me. I've edited my answer to include appending to the text file.